# How can i set a session variable in jquery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

Can anyone help me how to set a session variable in Jquery. Actually My requirement is like this:-

I am having a popup in html file. When i click the link, the popup opens. However, if i set the session expire , the popup should not open. So, when i click on the link, if session expires, the popup should not open but should redirect to targeted page. How can i do this?? My TL told me to google this but didn't found actually what i required. He suggested me to set session in Jquery. Is there any alternative for this?? As i am a newbie to Jquery, any code snippets are higly appreciated.please help me..

Comment: you can use session cookies in javascript. Example is given at http://blog.lysender.com/2011/08/setting-session-only-cookie-via-javascript/ and http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/cookie.shtml

Answer (score 1):

If you are needing to do this in .NET MVC you can do it as such.  Below is a an example:

Controller:

```
    if (Session["pageInitCounter"] == null)
    {
        Session["pageInitCounter"] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int counter = Convert.ToInt32(Session["pageInitCounter"]);
        counter++;
        Session["pageInitCounter"] = counter;
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.Hidden("pageInitCounter", Session["pageInitCounter"])
```

Javascript:

```
alert($("#pageInitCounter").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using localStorage like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var notSeen = localStorage['seen'];
    if (!notSeen) {
        // open popup
        localStorage['seen'] = "yes";
    }
});
```

Alternatively, use may as well try using a hidden field for this purpose.

Please visit the below links for more information.  This should satisfy your requirement

http://forums.asp.net/t/1499296.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1672519.aspx/1